# Using CKAN with the Cosign SSO system and LDAP

Tags: ldap, ckan, cosign-api

I'm using CKAN with Apache and an SSO system called Cosign. Cosign works as an authenticator in Apache and ends up setting REMOTE_USER before the python code fires up. What I'm trying to do is use LDAP user lookup based on that preset REMOTE_USER. Can I do that with the CKAN ldap plugin (http://extensions.ckan.org/extension/ldap/)? Any advice greatly appreciated - I'm a Python and CKAN novice.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that [ckanext-ldap](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/ckanext-ldap) doesn't do that. What it does is provide a custom login form (username and password) that authenticates the credentials via LDAP. It then creates a session for the corresponding CKAN user, creating a user account first if required. Having it do anything else would require customisation of the extension although there are a number of options documented in its readme that alter the behaviour in small ways.

Whether ckanext-ldap would be a suitable extension to build upon to achieve what you want depends on what you want to do, which isn't clear from your question.